# ¿Cómo unir estas dos rutas correctamente?

Tags: laravel

Tengo en mi archivo de rutas esto:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('content', 'ContentController');
});
```

Y necesito agregar esta, por temas de permisos:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
});
```

Esto estaría correcto?

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('content', 'ContentController');
  });
});
```

Comment: Si, es correcto

Comment: Muchas Gracias!